# How to add properties to an object when inheriting interfaces

Tags: typescript

To sum up my problem, I have an interface, User with an 'attributes' object filled with properties. I have another interface SpecialUser in which the 'attributes' object needs to contain properties that are not present on User. Currently, the new attributes object is overwriting the old one. I can get it to work by pasting in all properties from the parent interface and then appending the later ones, but that's not the most ideal solution.

```
export interface User{
  attributes: {
     full_name: string;
  }
}

export interface SpecialUser extends User {
  attributes: {
     occupation: string;
  }
}
```

What I want is for SpecialUser's 'attributes' to contain the fields on User's 'attributes' in addition to its new properties (so it would contain both full_name and occupation). The actual result is complete overwrite.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use an intersection type.

```js
interface User {
  attributes: {
    full_name: string;
  };
}

type SpecialUser = {
  attributes: {
    occupation: string;
  };
} & User;

const user: SpecialUser = {
  attributes: {
    occupation: "job",
    full_name: "name"
  }
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyycYYUwARgK6ToBcOBRRMVANmwPohwC2EDdGVABzANxNkAXwn4pBAmACeABxQBlNQmBw2GLAF5GhYqXLVaDPCaIB7BAioqSwWyEHCQ4yTIJTkAGRomFCyBAhuQshUIQyaENq6+lDIRtZEJMIWEPTGzMj2js5gru7IAEQAVrYU5QA0kizsXDz8DOWtEOU+frJAA)

Comment: This is called an intersection type not union type.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this fit your use case?

```
export interface User{
  attributes: {
     full_name?: string;
     occupation?: string;
  }
}
```

or since you're really modifying the attributes

```
export interface Attributes{
    full_name: string;
}

export interface SpecialAttributes extends Attributes {
    //has all other properties of original attributes (i.e. full_name)
    occupation: string;
}

export interface User{
    attributes: Attributes
}

export interface SpecialUser extends User {
    attributes: SpecialAttributes //overrides original attributes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem, but wanted to keep it as interfaces and not types. This is similar to skovy's answer and only moves the intersection into the interface:

```
interface User {
  attributes: {
    full_name: string;
  };
}

interface SpecialUser extends User {
  attributes: {
    occupation: string;
  } & User["attributes"];
};

const user: SpecialUser = {
  attributes: {
    occupation: "job",
    full_name: "name"
  }
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyycYYUwARgK6ToBcOBRRMVANmwPohwC2EDdGVABzANxNkAXwn4pBAqEixEKAMoAHCAmBw2GLBAAekEABN0aTFEaFipctVoM8dogHsECKhpLB3IILCIOKSUsgAZFbQANoARCTCThDocQC6sjIK+AgBQshU1gya2rr61sgAvLZEiY40KS6SHl4+fgEMcQBW7hRxADTNyKwc3HwCyHE8-HFhBFn4QA)